# How to post http request in component and update it?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios

These days,I'm working with `react` and `redux`,but I get stuck with posting http requests,I'm using `axios` to post http requests,and try many times or demos from the internet.None of them work in my program.I just want to call some APIs and update my components.

And I always got Error `TypeError getsimpleresult is not a function`,and can't call this function,I know it's just a small case.

**Can anyone help me fix it and give me a correct demo.Thanks.**

Here is my code:

**reducers.js**

```
const initState = {
    simple_result_value: {}
};

export default function simple_result_reduce(state = initState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'query_evaluation_simple_result':
            return {
                ...state,
                simple_result_value: action.simple_result_value
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

**action.js**

```
const simpleresultaction = (data) => ({
    type: 'GET_VALUE',
    result_value: data
});


export const getsimpleresult = () => async(dispatch, getState) => {
    try {
        let response = await post_http("/some/api", params);
        await dispatch(simpleresultaction(response.data))
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('HTTP post error: ', error)
    }
};
```

**component.js**

```
import React, {PropTypes, Component} from 'react'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as simpleActions from '../actions/simple_reuslt'

@connect( state => state,dispatch => bindActionCreators({simpleActions}, dispatch) )
export default class Simple_result_component extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.getsimpleresult();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <header className="header">
            </header>
        )
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I can see you are making use of `bindActionCreators` to bind the action to props as `simpleResult` however you are directly using the function. I suggest you should be extracting it like

```
componentWillMount() {
        this.props.simpleActions.getsimpleresult();
    }
```

also try changing the `connect` as

```
@connect(state => (state), dispatch => ({simpleActions: bindActionCreators(simpleActions, dispatch)}))
```

Comment: Yeah,I tried it too,but sill error `Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.`

Comment: could you do `console.log(this.props)` in the component and see if you get simpleActions. Also could you post the result you get

Comment: Thanks for your reminding,although your answer did not solve the problem, but gave me great hints.I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code example looks good. I guess your path to the actions is wrong:

```
import * as simpleActions from '../actions/simple_reuslt'
```

Can you please check the file name **simple_reuslt**? Here I mean wrong writing of **reuslt**.

Comment: Alright. Then check @Shubham answer. Maybe it's related to wrong actions invocation. I guess too it should be `this.props.simpleActions.getsimpleresult()`